# <a href=mysite.com> shown in Magento searchbox

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0, javascript, css, html

the `Search...` disappeared from inside of the Magento Frontend search box and `<a href=mysite.com>` shown instead!
how can i solve it?

Comment: could you any screen shot or url of the site

Comment: Dokanche.com
@MeenakshiSundaramR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you modify your search PHTML (probably app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml), exactly the JS which sets the value of the input and removes it on active.
See

> ```
>     //<![CDATA[
>         var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<a href=dokanche.com>');
>         searchForm.initAutocomplete('http://dokanche.com/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/', 'search_autocomplete');
>     //]]>
> ```

There you can change the text `<a href=dokanche.com>` for anything you want, for example `Search...`.